# Avoid rate limitation (Error: 420) in twitter streaming api

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to fetch streaming data from the twitter-streaming-api using the `tweepy` library in python. However, even after a lot of trials I am not able to get any `data` or print it as done in the `on_data` method. It's giving the 420 error message. How can I avoid it?

```
import io
import json
import time
import tweepy


access_token = 'XXXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXX'
consumer_key = 'XXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXX'

class MyListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

    def on_data(self, tweetdata):
        data = json.loads(tweetdata)           
        print(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_secret=consumer_secret,consumer_key=consumer_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

myListener = MyListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myListener)
myStream.filter(languages='en',track=['@NBA'],async=True)
myStream.disconnect()
```

Comment: what is the constraints? only request-count-limit? for example 100 requests per minute?

Comment: @YaserKH Sorry, newbie here. Is there a way I can check how many requests per minute I am making? or Do I need to add such a constraint in the request?

Comment: Did you check this page? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html

Comment: as one general solution you can use Redis (or some thing like it) to keep state of all limitation and before send request to API check that limitation state and decide to make a wait or send request